# Trying to create a database using sql in python, Error issue

Tags: python, sql, database, api

```
import json
import urllib
import sqlite3

def loading()
   url = 'https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?page=1' # URL for API 1-5json_obj = urllib.urlopen(url)
   response = urllib.urlopen(url)
   data = json.load(response) # loads the url and set it into data variable

   for item in data[0].keys():
       print(item)
   return data               # Get the keys

# def loading():
# print " LOADING API(s)"
# urllib.urlopen('https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?page=1')
# temp = json.dumps(data[1])
# print (json.dumps(data[1]))
# print (" ")
def createDB(data):
   conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
   c = conn.cursor()
   # Create table
   c.execute('''CREATE TABLE example
        (description text, title text, url text, company_logo text, company text, id integer primary key, company_url text, how_to_apply text,
        location text, type text, created_at timestamp)''')
   temp_values = list(tuple())
   for item in temp:
       list_of_values = [ v for k,v in item.items()]
       tuple_of_values = tuple(list_of_values)
       temp_values.append(tuple_of_values)
   c.executemany('INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', temp_values)


def main():
data = createDB()
createDB(data)

main()
```

---

im having trouble running the program I get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/Users/John/PycharmProjects/project1/Test.py", line 42, in main()
>   File "/Users/John/PycharmProjects/project1/Test.py", line 39, in main
>   data = createDB() TypeError: createDB() takes exactly 1 argument (0
>   given) Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: You don't provide any arguments in this statement `data = createDB()`. But your function requires a parameter, as your error suggests.

Comment: Furthermore, you have indentation errors and **WHY** do you call `createDB(...` twice?

Comment: @stovfl the indentation is usually from when they copy it incorrectly...

Comment: @istackz use triple \` at the beginning of code and again at the end in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to do this:

```
data = loading()
createDB(data)
```

Comment: I think so too.